# Lagged correlation (cross-correlation) does not seem to be correct with ccf in R

Tags: r, cross-correlation

## Goal

I have gas pedal position and the corresponding acceleration rate of several car drives. There is a time lag between the change in position of gas pedal and the resulting acceleration. I want to estimate this lag by using the lagged correlation between these two variables. One example is shown below:

[image]

## Data and CCF

Data for one driver is below.

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(frames = c(90956, 90957, 90958, 90959, 90960, 
90961, 90962, 90963, 90964, 90965, 90966, 90967, 90968, 90969, 
90970, 90971, 90972, 90973, 90974, 90975, 90976, 90977, 90978, 
90979, 90980, 90981, 90982, 90983, 90984, 90985, 90986, 90987, 
90988, 90989, 90990, 90991, 90992, 90993, 90994, 90995, 90996, 
90997, 90998, 90999, 91000, 91001, 91002, 91003, 91004, 91005, 
91006, 91007, 91008, 91009, 91010, 91011, 91012, 91013, 91014, 
91015, 91016, 91017, 91018, 91019, 91020, 91021, 91022, 91023, 
91024, 91025, 91026, 91027, 91028, 91029, 91030, 91031, 91032, 
91033, 91034, 91035, 91036, 91037, 91038, 91039, 91040, 91041, 
91042, 91043, 91044, 91045, 91046, 91047, 91048, 91049, 91050, 
91051, 91052, 91053, 91054, 91055, 91056, 91057, 91058, 91059, 
91060, 91061, 91062, 91063, 91064, 91065, 91066, 91067, 91068, 
91069, 91070, 91071, 91072, 91073, 91074, 91075, 91076, 91077, 
91078, 91079, 91080, 91081, 91082, 91083, 91084, 91085, 91086, 
91087, 91088, 91089, 91090, 91091, 91092, 91093, 91094, 91095, 
91096, 91097, 91098, 91099, 91100, 91101, 91102, 91103, 91104, 
91105, 91106, 91107, 91108, 91109, 91110, 91111, 91112, 91113, 
91114, 91115, 91116, 91117, 91118, 91119, 91120, 91121, 91122, 
91123, 91124, 91125, 91126, 91127, 91128, 91129, 91130, 91131, 
91132, 91133, 91134, 91135, 91136, 91137, 91138, 91139, 91140, 
91141, 91142, 91143, 91144, 91145, 91146, 91147, 91148, 91149, 
91150, 91151, 91152, 91153, 91154, 91155, 91156, 91157, 91158, 
91159, 91160, 91161, 91162, 91163, 91164, 91165, 91166, 91167, 
91168, 91169, 91170, 91171, 91172, 91173, 91174, 91175, 91176, 
91177, 91178, 91179, 91180, 91181, 91182, 91183, 91184, 91185, 
91186, 91187, 91188, 91189, 91190, 91191, 91192, 91193, 91194, 
91195, 91196, 91197, 91198, 91199, 91200, 91201, 91202, 91203, 
91204, 91205, 91206, 91207, 91208, 91209, 91210, 91211, 91212, 
91213, 91214, 91215, 91216, 91217, 91218, 91219, 91220, 91221, 
91222, 91223, 91224, 91225, 91226, 91227, 91228, 91229, 91230, 
91231, 91232, 91233, 91234, 91235, 91236, 91237, 91238, 91239, 
91240, 91241, 91242, 91243, 91244, 91245, 91246, 91247, 91248, 
91249, 91250, 91251, 91252, 91253, 91254, 91255, 91256, 91257, 
91258, 91259, 91260, 91261, 91262, 91263, 91264, 91265, 91266, 
91267, 91268, 91269, 91270, 91271, 91272, 91273, 91274, 91275, 
91276, 91277, 91278, 91279, 91280, 91281, 91282, 91283, 91284, 
91285, 91286, 91287, 91288, 91289, 91290, 91291, 91292, 91293, 
91294, 91295, 91296, 91297, 91298, 91299, 91300, 91301, 91302, 
91303, 91304, 91305, 91306, 91307, 91308, 91309, 91310, 91311, 
91312, 91313, 91314, 91315, 91316, 91317, 91318, 91319, 91320, 
91321, 91322, 91323, 91324, 91325, 91326, 91327, 91328, 91329, 
91330, 91331, 91332, 91333, 91334, 91335, 91336, 91337, 91338, 
91339, 91340, 91341, 91342, 91343, 91344, 91345, 91346, 91347, 
91348, 91349, 91350, 91351, 91352, 91353, 91354, 91355, 91356, 
91357, 91358, 91359, 91360, 91361, 91362, 91363, 91364, 91365, 
91366, 91367, 91368, 91369, 91370, 91371, 91372, 91373, 91374, 
91375, 91376, 91377, 91378, 91379, 91380, 91381, 91382, 91383, 
91384, 91385, 91386, 91387, 91388, 91389, 91390, 91391, 91392, 
91393, 91394, 91395, 91396, 91397, 91398, 91399, 91400, 91401, 
91402, 91403, 91404, 91405, 91406, 91407, 91408, 91409, 91410, 
91411, 91412, 91413, 91414, 91415, 91416, 91417, 91418, 91419, 
91420, 91421, 91422, 91423, 91424, 91425, 91426, 91427, 91428, 
91429, 91430, 91431, 91432, 91433, 91434, 91435, 91436, 91437
), ED_gas_pedal_pos = c(0.558, 0.558, 0.557, 0.557, 0.557, 0.556, 
0.555, 0.551, 0.548, 0.543, 0.539, 0.533, 0.529, 0.526, 0.521, 
0.518, 0.513, 0.509, 0.503, 0.497, 0.491, 0.483, 0.472, 0.462, 
0.449, 0.434, 0.422, 0.409, 0.398, 0.388, 0.379, 0.368, 0.356, 
0.345, 0.335, 0.323, 0.311, 0.299, 0.286, 0.275, 0.265, 0.257, 
0.246, 0.235, 0.223, 0.213, 0.203, 0.197, 0.187, 0.181, 0.173, 
0.167, 0.16, 0.155, 0.149, 0.143, 0.14, 0.134, 0.129, 0.123, 
0.119, 0.114, 0.108, 0.103, 0.095, 0.086, 0.075, 0.062, 0.048, 
0.031, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ED_acc_mps2_lag = c(0.31, 
0.3, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 0.31, 
0.31, 0.31, 0.3, 0.31, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.29, 0.3, 0.29, 
0.29, 0.29, 0.29, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.28, 0.27, 0.27, 0.26, 0.26, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.23, 0.23, 0.22, 0.22, 0.2, 0.2, 0.18, 0.18, 0.16, 
0.16, 0.14, 0.13, 0.12, 0.11, 0.09, 0.07, 0.06, 0.04, 0.03, 0.01, 
0, -0.02, -0.03, -0.05, -0.06, -0.08, -0.09, -0.11, -0.12, -0.15, 
-0.16, -0.18, -0.19, -0.21, -0.23, -0.25, -0.26, -0.27, -0.29, 
-0.31, -0.33, -0.34, -0.36, -0.38, -0.39, -0.41, -0.42, -0.44, 
-0.46, -0.47, -0.48, -0.49, -0.52, -0.53, -0.54, -0.55, -0.57, 
-0.58, -0.59, -0.6, -0.61, -0.62, -0.63, -0.64, -0.64, -0.66, 
-0.66, -0.67, -0.67, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.7, -0.71, -0.71, 
-0.71, -0.71, -0.71, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.73, -0.73, 
-0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.74, -0.74, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.74, 
-0.74, -0.73, -0.73, -0.74, -0.74, -0.74, -0.73, -0.73, -0.74, 
-0.74, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.74, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, 
-0.74, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, 
-0.72, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, -0.72, -0.73, -0.73, -0.73, 
-0.72, -0.72, -0.73, -0.73, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.73, -0.73, 
-0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.73, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.73, 
-0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, 
-0.71, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.71, -0.71, -0.72, -0.72, 
-0.72, -0.71, -0.71, -0.72, -0.72, -0.72, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, 
-0.72, -0.72, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, -0.72, -0.71, -0.71, 
-0.71, -0.71, -0.72, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, 
-0.71, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, -0.7, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, 
-0.7, -0.7, -0.71, -0.71, -0.71, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.71, 
-0.71, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.71, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, 
-0.7, -0.71, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.69, -0.7, -0.7, 
-0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.69, -0.69, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.7, -0.69, 
-0.69, -0.69, -0.7, -0.7, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.7, -0.7, 
-0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, 
-0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.68, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, 
-0.69, -0.68, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.68, -0.68, 
-0.68, -0.69, -0.69, -0.69, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, 
-0.69, -0.69, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.69, 
-0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, 
-0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.68, -0.68, 
-0.68, -0.68, -0.68, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.68, -0.68, -0.68, 
-0.68, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.68, -0.67, 
-0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, 
-0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.66, -0.66, -0.67, 
-0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, 
-0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.67, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, 
-0.66, -0.66, -0.67, -0.67, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, 
-0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.65, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, 
-0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.65, -0.65, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, 
-0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, 
-0.65, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.66, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, 
-0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.66, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, 
-0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.65, -0.64, 
-0.64, -0.65, -0.65)), row.names = c(NA, -482L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

#### Code for plot shown above

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(frames, scale(ED_gas_pedal_pos), color = "pedal")) +
  geom_line(aes(frames, scale(ED_acc_mps2_lag), color = "acc"))
```

### Estimation of lagged correlation using CCF

I used the `ccf` function to estimate the lagged correlation:

```
library(magrittr)

df %$%
  ccf(ED_gas_pedal_pos, ED_acc_mps2_lag, 
      plot = TRUE, lag.max = 100)
```

[image]

The maximum correlation was at the lag of zero:

```
Find_Max_CCF<- function(a,b)
{
  d <- ccf(a, b, plot = FALSE, lag.max = 100)
  cor = d$acf[,,1]
  lag = d$lag[,,1]
  res = data.frame(cor,lag)
  res_max = res[which.max(res$cor),]
  return(res_max)
} 

> Find_Max_CCF(df$ED_gas_pedal_pos, df$ED_acc_mps2_lag)
          cor lag
101 0.8592041   0
```

## How do I estimate the lagged correlation correctly?

As you can see in the first plot, there is clearly a time lag of about 60 frames or 1 sec (1 frame = 1/60 s). But `ccf` shows a lagged correlation of 0. How can I estimate this lag correctly?